# filtered elements in jagged list in nested dictionary using awkward

Tags: python, dictionary, jagged-arrays, awkward-array

I have a large nested dictionary with jagged list 'c' :

```
x = {'first_block': 
     {'unit1': {'a': (3,5,4), 'b': 23, 'c': [10]}, 
      'unit2': {'a': (5,8,7), 'b': 15, 'c': [20,10]}, 
      'unit10k': {'a': (2,4,9), 'b': 10, 'c': [6,10,20,5]}},
     
      'second_block': 
       {'unit1' : {'a': (8,20,14), 'b': 10, 'c': [17,12,9]}, 
        'unit2' : {'a': (9,25,50), 'b': 15, 'c': [17,15,9,4,12]}, 
        'unit12k': {'a': (12,24,9), 'b': 23, 'c': [12,22,15,4]}},
     
      'millionth_block': 
      {'unit1': {'a': (35,64,85), 'b': 64, 'c': [50]}, 
       'unit2': {'a': (56,23,34), 'b': 55, 'c': [89,59,77]},
       'unit5k': {'a': (90,28,12), 'b': 85, 'c': [48,90,27,59]}}}
```

The elements of 'c' are point labels.

For every unique point label in 'c' I want to produce a filtered list of the corresponding value in 'b',

so for example 'first_block' has unique elements in 'c' of: 5, 6, 10, 20

and i want to obtain/extract the following lists for each 'block', to list each value of 'b' associated with a specific value in 'c' e.g.

```
first_block:
5: [10]
6: [10]
10: [10,15,23]
20: [10,15]
second_block:
4: [15,23]
9: [10,15]
12: [10,15,23]
15: [15,23]
17: [10,15]
22: [23]
etc.
```

Any thoughts on how to create this outcome given that 'c' is jagged?

Have been trying to do this by converting to Awkward arrays but documentation is currently sparse, and really don't understand how to do this in Awkward.

Also open to pythonic suggestions which don't involve Awkward

Comment: It may be myself but I can't store that in a dict. I get syntax error second line, and it is pretty nested right. Could you check?

Comment: Apologies have corrected some typos in the example dict, you should find that works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it reproduces exactly what you want (including sorting)

```
x = {'first_block': 
     {'unit1': {'a': (3,5,4), 'b': 23, 'c': [10]}, 
      'unit2': {'a': (5,8,7), 'b': 15, 'c': [20,10]}, 
      'unit10k': {'a': (2,4,9), 'b': 10, 'c': [6,10,20,5]}},
     
      'second_block': 
       {'unit1' : {'a': (8,20,14), 'b': 10, 'c': [17,12,9]}, 
        'unit2' : {'a': (9,25,50), 'b': 15, 'c': [17,15,9,4,12]}, 
        'unit12k': {'a': (12,24,9), 'b': 23, 'c': [12,22,15,4]}},
     
      'millionth_block': 
      {'unit1': {'a': (35,64,85), 'b': 64, 'c': [50]}, 
       'unit2': {'a': (56,23,34), 'b': 55, 'c': [89,59,77]},
       'unit5k': {'a': (90,28,12), 'b': 85, 'c': [48,90,27,59]}}}  

results = {}

for key in x.keys(): # Block level key
    results[key] = {}

    for unit in x[key].keys(): # Unit level key in subdict
        for value in x[key][unit]['c']: #List of values in c
            if value not in results[key].keys():
                #You assign a c level key, create a list
                results[key][value] = []

            #And append values from b
            results[key][value].append(x[key][unit]['b'])

    #You sort your dict by key/item
    results[key] = dict(sorted(results[key].items()))

for key in results:
    print (key)
    for value in results[key].keys():
        print (value,results[key][value])
```

Output:

```
first_block
5 [10]
6 [10]
10 [23, 15, 10]
20 [15, 10]
second_block
4 [15, 23]
9 [10, 15]
12 [10, 15, 23]
15 [15, 23]
17 [10, 15]
22 [23]
millionth_block
27 [85]
48 [85]
50 [64]
59 [55, 85]
77 [55]
89 [55]
90 [85]
```

Comment: Awesome work... This worked well and executed in 1.08 seconds for 1100 blocks. Thank you for answering the question, am happy with this. Would still like to see if anyone can do awkward solution to out perform this?

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to give an Awkward Array solution to this.

First of all, we need to know what in your dataset is really scaling up. I understand that you could have millions of blocks, but that means that you shouldn't represent them with a dict that has unique string-valued keys. The cost of creating strings, comparing strings, and looking things up by strings (though that's helped quite a bit by the dict's hash table) is not a good way to scale, especially if the only information in those strings is an ordering.

It also seems to me that you have a variable number of units (by the fact that the last one is named "unit10k", "unit12k", and "unit5k").

Finally, it took me several re-reads of your problem statement, but it seems that the field named "a" doesn't enter into the problem. I'll ignore it.

Therefore, I'd say your data structure would be better as:

```py
as_python = [
    # first block
    [
        # unit 1
        {"b": 23, "c": [10]},
        # unit 2
        {"b": 15, "c": [20, 10]},
        # ...
        # unit 10k
        {"b": 10, "c": [6, 10, 20, 5]},
    ],
    # second block
    [
        # unit 1
        {"b": 10, "c": [17, 12, 9]},
        # unit 2
        {"b": 15, "c": [17, 15, 9, 4, 12]},
        # ...
        # unit 12k
        {"b": 23, "c": [12, 22, 15, 4]},
    ],
    # ...
    # millionth block
    [
        # unit 1
        {"b": 64, "c": [50]},
        # unit 2
        {"b": 55, "c": [89, 59, 77]},
        # ...
        # unit 15k
        {"b": 85, "c": [48, 90, 27, 59]},
    ],
]
```

A Pythonic solution to this would be

```py
results = []
for block in as_python:
    block_result = {}
    for unit in block:
        b = unit["b"]    # only look up b once
        for c in unit["c"]:
            if c not in block_result:
                block_result[c] = []
            block_result[c].append(b)
    results.append(block_result)
```

which results in

```py
[
    {10: [23, 15, 10], 20: [15, 10], 6: [10], 5: [10]},
    {17: [10, 15], 12: [10, 15, 23], 9: [10, 15], 15: [15, 23], 4: [15, 23], 22: [23]},
    {50: [64], 89: [55], 59: [55, 85], 77: [55], 48: [85], 90: [85], 27: [85]},
]
```

which should be pretty fast. (Short loops using only builtin Python types is surprisingly fast for an uncompiled, dynamically typed virtual machine. In my experience, using only builtin Python types is key.)

As for Awkward Array, I can only get halfway there using vectorized (i.e. "NumPy-like") operations before invoking Numba (JIT-compiled `for` loops), which reveals that the library needs a "groupby" function.

Of course, you can do the whole thing in Numba, which tends to be the fastest solution overall, but this problem depends crucially on grouping and uniqueness, which in Python is most naturally done with dicts or sets, but it's hard to get Numba to deduce the type of anything beyond pure numbers and arrays. (In order to JIT compile the code and make it fast, Numba must know their types, but Python type annotations are recent enough that they're still being incorporated into Numba.)

So let's start by making the above data structure an Awkward Array. Depending on your data source, there are different ways to do this ([this part of the documentation](https://awkward-array.org/how-to-convert.html) is complete), but I'll just let `ak.Array` iterate over the above Python data structure.

```py
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> as_awkward = ak.Array(as_python)
```

Ordinarily, if we have a "all combinations of X and Y" problem, we want to use [ak.cartesian](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.cartesian.html). We can't use it right away here because the "b" data and "c" data have different depths:

```py
>>> as_awkward = ak.Array(as_python)
>>> as_awkward.b
<Array [[23, 15, 10], ... 23], [64, 55, 85]] type='3 * var * int64'>
>>> as_awkward.c
<Array [[[10], [20, 10], ... [48, 90, 27, 59]]] type='3 * var * var * int64'>
>>> as_awkward.type
3 * var * {"b": int64, "c": var * int64}
>>> as_awkward.b.type
3 * var * int64
>>> as_awkward.c.type
3 * var * var * int64
```

To make them match, we can create a new axis using `np.newaxis` (a.k.a. `None`, but I like to be explicit):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bprime = as_awkward.b[:, :, np.newaxis]
>>> bprime
<Array [[[23], [15], [10, ... 64], [55], [85]]] type='3 * var * 1 * int64'>
>>> bprime.type
3 * var * 1 * int64
>>> as_awkward.c.type
3 * var * var * int64
```

Now we can take the Cartesian products within each unit to make lists of b-c pairs (`axis=2`).

```py
>>> combinations = ak.cartesian({"c": as_awkward.c, "b": bprime}, axis=2)
>>> combinations
<Array [[[{c: 10, b: 23}], ... c: 59, b: 85}]]] type='3 * var * var * {"c": int6...'>
>>> combinations.type
3 * var * var * {"c": int64, "b": int64}
>>> combinations.tolist()
[
    [
        [
            [{"c": 10, "b": 23}]
        ],
        [
            [{"c": 20, "b": 15}],
            [{"c": 10, "b": 15}]],
        [
            [{"c": 6, "b": 10}],
            [{"c": 10, "b": 10}],
            [{"c": 20, "b": 10}],
            [{"c": 5, "b": 10}],
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            [{"c": 17, "b": 10}],
            [{"c": 12, "b": 10}],
            [{"c": 9, "b": 10}]
        ],
        [
            [{"c": 17, "b": 15}],
            [{"c": 15, "b": 15}],
            [{"c": 9, "b": 15}],
            [{"c": 4, "b": 15}],
            [{"c": 12, "b": 15}],
        ],
        [
            [{"c": 12, "b": 23}],
            [{"c": 22, "b": 23}],
            [{"c": 15, "b": 23}],
            [{"c": 4, "b": 23}],
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            [{"c": 50, "b": 64}]
        ],
        [
            [{"c": 89, "b": 55}],
            [{"c": 59, "b": 55}],
            [{"c": 77, "b": 55}]
        ],
        [
            [{"c": 48, "b": 85}],
            [{"c": 90, "b": 85}],
            [{"c": 27, "b": 85}],
            [{"c": 59, "b": 85}],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Now we have too much structure: as long as the "b" and "c" values are properly connected, you want to mix all units in a block because you're interested in uniqueness of "c" within each *block*.

```py
>>> flattened = ak.flatten(combinations, axis=-1)
>>> flattened
<Array [[{c: 10, b: 23}, ... c: 59, b: 85}]] type='3 * var * {"c": int64, "b": i...'>
>>> flattened.type
3 * var * {"c": int64, "b": int64}
>>> flattened.tolist()
[
    [
        {"c": 10, "b": 23},
        {"c": 20, "b": 15},
        {"c": 10, "b": 15},
        {"c": 6, "b": 10},
        {"c": 10, "b": 10},
        {"c": 20, "b": 10},
        {"c": 5, "b": 10},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 17, "b": 10},
        {"c": 12, "b": 10},
        {"c": 9, "b": 10},
        {"c": 17, "b": 15},
        {"c": 15, "b": 15},
        {"c": 9, "b": 15},
        {"c": 4, "b": 15},
        {"c": 12, "b": 15},
        {"c": 12, "b": 23},
        {"c": 22, "b": 23},
        {"c": 15, "b": 23},
        {"c": 4, "b": 23},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 50, "b": 64},
        {"c": 89, "b": 55},
        {"c": 59, "b": 55},
        {"c": 77, "b": 55},
        {"c": 48, "b": 85},
        {"c": 90, "b": 85},
        {"c": 27, "b": 85},
        {"c": 59, "b": 85},
    ],
]
```

Sorting and uniqueness are at the bleeding edge of Awkward Array's capabilities; there are some functions that have been written internally that just haven't been exposed in Python, let alone documented. Fortunately, [ak.sort](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.sort.html) and [ak.argsort](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.argsort.html) are documented. We ultimately want to group these b-c pairs by c, we can at least sort them:

```py
>>> sorted = flattened[ak.argsort(flattened.c, axis=-1)]
>>> sorted
<Array [[{c: 5, b: 10}, ... {c: 90, b: 85}]] type='3 * var * {"c": int64, "b": i...'>
>>> sorted.type
3 * var * {"c": int64, "b": int64}
>>> sorted.tolist()
[
    [
        {"c": 5, "b": 10},
        {"c": 6, "b": 10},
        {"c": 10, "b": 23},
        {"c": 10, "b": 15},
        {"c": 10, "b": 10},
        {"c": 20, "b": 15},
        {"c": 20, "b": 10},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 4, "b": 15},
        {"c": 4, "b": 23},
        {"c": 9, "b": 10},
        {"c": 9, "b": 15},
        {"c": 12, "b": 10},
        {"c": 12, "b": 15},
        {"c": 12, "b": 23},
        {"c": 15, "b": 15},
        {"c": 15, "b": 23},
        {"c": 17, "b": 10},
        {"c": 17, "b": 15},
        {"c": 22, "b": 23},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 27, "b": 85},
        {"c": 48, "b": 85},
        {"c": 50, "b": 64},
        {"c": 59, "b": 55},
        {"c": 59, "b": 85},
        {"c": 77, "b": 55},
        {"c": 89, "b": 55},
        {"c": 90, "b": 85},
    ],
]
```

And now we really, really wish we had a "groupby" function, but there just isn't one. It would be a natural addition and perhaps should be a [feature request](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature&template=feature-request.md&title=).

So at this point, we switch to Numba. The problem is much simpler than the original problem because the data to group are already sorted: we just need to see when a value changes to insert boundaries. Awkward Arrays can be passed as arguments into Numba, but they're immutable. To make new arrays, use an [ak.ArrayBuilder](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.ArrayBuilder.html). Note: when developing a function like this, do it in small steps and remove `@nb.njit` to try it without JIT-compilation (to be sure you're making the right thing before trying to solve type errors).

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def groupby(input, output):
    for block in input:
        output.begin_list()
        output.begin_list()
        last = block[0].c  # note: assumes that len(block) >= 1
        for unit in block:
            if unit.c != last:
                output.end_list()
                output.begin_list()
            output.append(unit)
            last = unit.c
        output.end_list()
        output.end_list()
    return output
```

The `input` is the array we just made (`sorted`), and the `output` is an ArrayBuilder that turns into a real array with `snapshot` (outside of Numba).

```py
>>> grouped = groupby(sorted, ak.ArrayBuilder()).snapshot()
>>> grouped
<Array [[[{c: 5, b: 10}], ... {c: 90, b: 85}]]] type='3 * var * var * {"c": int6...'>
>>> grouped.type
3 * var * var * {"c": int64, "b": int64}
>>> grouped.tolist()
[
    [
        [{"c": 5, "b": 10}],
        [{"c": 6, "b": 10}],
        [{"c": 10, "b": 23}, {"c": 10, "b": 15}, {"c": 10, "b": 10}],
        [{"c": 20, "b": 15}, {"c": 20, "b": 10}],
    ],
    [
        [{"c": 4, "b": 15}, {"c": 4, "b": 23}],
        [{"c": 9, "b": 10}, {"c": 9, "b": 15}],
        [{"c": 12, "b": 10}, {"c": 12, "b": 15}, {"c": 12, "b": 23}],
        [{"c": 15, "b": 15}, {"c": 15, "b": 23}],
        [{"c": 17, "b": 10}, {"c": 17, "b": 15}],
        [{"c": 22, "b": 23}],
    ],
    [
        [{"c": 27, "b": 85}],
        [{"c": 48, "b": 85}],
        [{"c": 50, "b": 64}],
        [{"c": 59, "b": 55}, {"c": 59, "b": 85}],
        [{"c": 77, "b": 55}],
        [{"c": 89, "b": 55}],
        [{"c": 90, "b": 85}],
    ],
]
```

Then you can fiddle with that output to get a desired structure. If you want to have a scalar "c" for each list "b", you'll want to use a `depth_limit` to keep [ak.zip](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.zip.html) from broadcasting it down to the deepest level.

```py
>>> ak.zip({"c": grouped.c[:, :, 0], "b": grouped.b}, depth_limit=2).tolist()
[
    [
        {"c": 5, "b": [10]},
        {"c": 6, "b": [10]},
        {"c": 10, "b": [23, 15, 10]},
        {"c": 20, "b": [15, 10]},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 4, "b": [15, 23]},
        {"c": 9, "b": [10, 15]},
        {"c": 12, "b": [10, 15, 23]},
        {"c": 15, "b": [15, 23]},
        {"c": 17, "b": [10, 15]},
        {"c": 22, "b": [23]},
    ],
    [
        {"c": 27, "b": [85]},
        {"c": 48, "b": [85]},
        {"c": 50, "b": [64]},
        {"c": 59, "b": [55, 85]},
        {"c": 77, "b": [55]},
        {"c": 89, "b": [55]},
        {"c": 90, "b": [85]},
    ],
]
```

If you want to build a report of that type in Numba directly, you can do it. (This is just to illustrate what the "begin_list" and such are doing—it's like "printing out" a structure, imagining `output.begin_list()` to print a `"["` and `output.begin_record()` to print a `"{"`, etc.)

```py
@nb.njit
def groupby(input, output):
    for block in input:
        output.begin_list()
        output.begin_record()
        output.field("c").integer(block[0].c)
        output.field("b")
        output.begin_list()
        last = block[0].c
        for unit in block:
            if unit.c != last:
                output.end_list()
                output.end_record()
                output.begin_record()
                output.field("c").integer(unit.c)
                output.field("b")
                output.begin_list()
            output.integer(unit.b)
            last = unit.c
        output.end_list()
        output.end_record()
        output.end_list()
    return output
```

and

```py
>>> grouped = groupby(sorted, ak.ArrayBuilder()).snapshot()
>>> grouped
<Array [[{c: 5, b: [10]}, ... c: 90, b: [85]}]] type='3 * var * {"c": int64, "b"...'>
>>> grouped.type
3 * var * {"c": int64, "b": var * int64}
>>> grouped.tolist()
# it's the same
```

As I said above, the absolutely fastest solution is likely to be doing everything in Numba. The Cartesian products, flattening, and sorting all create partially new arrays (reusing as much from the inputs as possible, which is why the Awkward Arrays have to be immutable), which involves allocations and multiple passes over the data. But it's hard to express problems involving dicts, lists, and sets in Numba because it needs typed dicts, lists, and sets. I tried using [Numba's typed dict](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-dict), but it complained about the values of the dict being lists, which are not hashable. (Dict *values* do not need to be hashable, so I wonder what's going on there.) Just as uniqueness and sorting are the bleeding edge of Awkward Array, typing dicts is the bleeding edge of Numba since the concept of typing in Python is itself rather new.

I didn't performance-test any of these proposed solutions.

Comment: This sir, is an awesome piece of analysis, there are some very useful observations in here particularly about current state of different libraries and suggestions on data structure. Just some background the stringed keys are artifact from trying to get our nested dict into Awkward using ak.from_iter(py_objects). The direction we were envisaging for Awakard was slicing and mapping, but not enough experience to frame it right. Still exploring at the moment but data volumes for this data are in the 50PB range, so efficiency becomes a thing. Thank you for your insights

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {'first_block': 
 {'unit1': {'a': (3,5,4), 'b': 23, 'c': [10]}, 
  'unit2': {'a': (5,8,7), 'b': 15, 'c': [20,10]}, 
  'unit10k': {'a': (2,4,9), 'b': 10, 'c': [6,10,20,5]}},
 
  'second_block': 
   {'unit1' : {'a': (8,20,14), 'b': 10, 'c': [17,12,9]}, 
    'unit2' : {'a': (9,25,50), 'b': 15, 'c': [17,15,9,4,12]}, 
    'unit12k': {'a': (12,24,9), 'b': 23, 'c': [12,22,15,4]}},
 
  'millionth_block': 
  {'unit1': {'a': (35,64,85), 'b': 64, 'c': [50]}, 
   'unit2': {'a': (56,23,34), 'b': 55, 'c': [89,59,77]},
   'unit5k': {'a': (90,28,12), 'b': 85, 'c': [48,90,27,59]}}}  
   
result = {};
for blocks in x.keys():
    cs = {};
    for unit in x[blocks].keys():
       for c in x[blocks][unit]['c']:
            #retrieve array of b value for the c key or take [], then concat the b value, then apply set function to remove double, then convert to list
            cs[str(c)] = list(set(((cs.get(str(c)) or []) + [x[blocks][unit]['b']])))
    result[blocks] = cs;

print(result);
```

Comment: That is the same as me but no pretty print and  no sort.

Comment: no pretty print but prettier list appending :D i work on algorithm no on pretty output haha

Comment: Still not sorting! If you work on algorythms, then make the bot or help me, I feel alone.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Daphoque, I liked the use of set to find uniqueness. It produced a usable result in 296ms. Although timing is not a fair comparison to @Synthase who has additional processes for output comprehension.